# Dropdown in templated column for ultrawebgrid does not function properly

Tags: drop-down-menu, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I have a templated column. I am using a Dropdown as header template and based on the value of the dropdown user sets, I update sigle DB record. Header drop down has nothing to do with the contents of the cells of that column. Everything works fine when the page is loaded and dropdown functions as expected.

As soon as I click anywhere on the gid and then click on the drop down, it behaves in a weird fashion i.e. it expands and then collapses. If I double click on the drop down it works as expected.

I am not able to understand what happens when I click inside the grid so that my drop down only responds to double click and not single click.

Here is the code snippet:

```
    <igtbl:TemplatedColumn BaseColumnName="Assigned" Key="Assigned" AllowResize="Free"  AllowRowFiltering="False"

                                AllowUpdate="Yes" Width="80px" Type="Custom" EditorControlID="assignTo" IsBound="false">

                                <Header Caption="Assigned To" ClickAction="SortSingle">

                                    <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="15" />

                                </Header>

                                    <HeaderTemplate>Assigned To <select id="AssignToDefault" width="40px" runat="server" name="AssignToDefault"><option value="0">-Select-</option><option value="1">User</option><option value="2">API</option></select>

                           </HeaderTemplate>

                                <Footer>

                                    <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="15" />

                                </Footer>

    </igtbl:TemplatedColumn>
```

I am trying to solve the issue since long. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on Infragistics Community:

http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/67149/340326.aspx#340326

**EDIT (in case link deprecates):**

I tested your scenario and was able to replicate the behavior in IE8 but not in Firefox.I suggest that you try disabling the activation behavior of the grid to see if that makes a difference:

UltraWebGrid1.DisplayLayout.ActivationObject.AllowActivation = false;

Alternatively you may want to consider using the WebCombo control in this scenario as it seems to be unaffected by the issue.

Please note that the UltraWebGrid control is now outdated and as of .NetAdvantage 2011 Volume 2 is no longer included in our product package. I would suggest that you consider switching to the WebDataGrid/WebHieararchicalDataGrid. More information regarding these controls is available at:

http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.2/CLR4.0/?page=Web_WebDataGrid_WebDataGrid.html

Additional samples demonstrating the features of these grids can be found at:
http://samples.infragistics.com/aspnet/

Thank you :)